# How does git diff actually identifies the lines that are deleted

Tags: git, github

For example as the diff shown in [here](https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/commit/d53489b5b2ad907d01957eb50ddf12dc3611d127), how does git identifies accurately that line no `86` is been deleted from `TemplateManagerInitializer.java`. First I thought that it is from `@@ -83,7 +97,6 @@` notation that the no of lines in the previous file `(7)`is greater than the current file `(6)` so one line is been deleted between the relevant range. But sometimes there can be situations where all 7 lines in the old file was deleted and completely new 6 lines were added. So can anyone explain me how git keep track of actual lines been deleted and added in a file. Thanks in advance

Comment: Vampire's answer is correct. Here's another way to think about it: the `@@` hunk header says "look near here", and then the diff hunk *underneath* the header says "expect to see this text; if and when you do, replace the subtracted lines with the added lines." Depending on what's applying the diff, a certain amount of "fuzziness" may be allowed: the hunk header says "look *near* lines 83-90" and Git (or `patch`) can look as high as line 53, or as low as line 113, if the fuzz factor is +/- 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The line that is deleted is there with the `-` prefix, so the applying tool exactly knows which line to delete and can check the context lines and range specification to be sure it is the right one.